# SELECT Mysql - Priorizando resultado que não estejam nulos

Tags: mysql, select

Olá,  tenho uma tabela com vários registros, que não são obrigatórios.

Preciso executar uma consulta, e trazer apenas o resultado que tenha mais informações que não estejam nulas.

Ex:

> ```
> ID | Col-A | Col-B | Col-C | Col-D
> ----------------------------------
> 1    null    null   true    true
> 2    true    null   true    true
> 3    null    null   null    true
> ```

Neste exemplo, o ID 2 tem tres valores preenchidos, preciso que meu `SELECT` retorne apenas ele.

Se ele não existisse, deveria retornar o registro ID 1, que tem 2 valores preenchidos.

E o menos importante, seria o ID 3 que possui apenas um valor preenchido.

Como fazer isto no Mysql, retornando apenas 1 registo, e que ele seja o mais importante (que tenha mais valores preenchidos ) ?

Comment: Conforme a resposta dos colegas, esta regra me atendeu:
`SELECT *, SUM( (CASE WHEN Col-A IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) + (CASE WHEN Col-B IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) + (CASE WHEN Col-C IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) + (CASE WHEN Col-D IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)  ) prioridade FROM tabela ORDER BY prioridade DESC LIMIT 1;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você consegue fazer isso no `ORDER BY`:

```
SELECT ID, Col-A, Col-B, Col-C, Col-D FROM tabela
ORDER BY (IF(Col-A IS NULL, 0, 1) + IF(Col-B IS NULL, 0, 1) + IF(Col-C IS NULL, 0, 1) + IF(Col-D IS NULL, 0, 1)) DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

A ideia é somar as colunas que não sejam nulas, ordenar decrescentemente e limitar o resultado em uma linha.

> Você pode perder um pouco de performance dependendo de quantos registros tem na tabela e dos índices configurados.

Comment: Legal a ideia @Roberto, fiz parecido só que acumulando um ponto para cada valor dentro do SELECT e ordenando por esta pontuação.
Praticamente a mesma lógica que vc usou.